# Django timezone.now() returning None

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-timezone

I know I could use auto_now_add equals True but it bugs me that I can't get this simple view to work.

Here is the view:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateListing(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.date = timezone.now()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        form = CreateListing()
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
                "form": form
            })
```

Here is the form:

```
class CreateListing(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ("name", "description", "bid")
```

Here is the model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    #date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def place(self):
        self.date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} going for {self.bid} since {self.date}"
```

I have tried removing the place function from the model, removing

```
form.save(commit=False)
```

and using datetime instead of timezone. I have wasted too many hours on this, please help!

The only way I can get something to work is creating an object through the shell and using the place function there. However, despite my timezone being set to America/Vancouver, it gives UTC time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the instance returned when using `commit=False`, and not the form, so:

```
        if form.is_valid:
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.date = timezone.now()
            instance.save()
```

or since you wrote a `place` method in your model:

```
        if form.is_valid:
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.place()
```

Although `place()` can probably be renamed to something better? But I would suggest just using `auto_now_add`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it!

You wouldn't also happen to know why the time zone isn't right despite being set, would you?

Comment: No worries! Where/how did you set your timezone?

Comment: I put "TIME_ZONE='America/Vancouver'" and "USE_TZ=True" in the settings

Comment: And timezone are you getting currently? Do you have any middleware that might change the timezone based on the request?

Comment: I'm not using any middleware that I know of; most of the settings are just default but I am getting UTC time anyway. I also tried to change the time zone to 'US/Pacific' and I noticed it works right through the admin but not through django forms.